# Numeric field validation not working in Mac safari

Tags: regex, safari, numeric

I have created input field and for validation I have put regex as "^[0-9]+$". It is validating for every device but when it comes it mac safari it is accepting every character number and space too. Can anyone please help with proper regex that will work for all device including mac safari.

I have tried regex as "^[0-9]+$" and /^\d{10}$/g. For not allowing space I found regex as /^\S*$/g. but I am trying how to combine number and not space in one regex.

Comment: Can you give more context about the environment? Which webframework are you using? Are you using wordpress or any other framework? Some executable code that makes the error reproducible always helps a lot.

Comment: I am using react and gatsby. There is a contact number field. As per requirement it should accept only numbers minlength should be 10 and maxlength should be 11. It should not accept any other character other than text. For that I have used regex as ^[0-9]+$ . It is working in all devices other than mac safari. In macsafari even though I have specified the field filed type should be number still it is accepting character space. I am trying to figure out regex that will satisfy mac safari browser.

Comment: do you get any error messages in the console when using safari?

Comment: No .. But I was able to resolve this issue using keydown rather than regex.